# To hide pseudo class content in a zero-height element on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, datatables

I use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), and want to customize the [header sorting labels](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html), to use icon font.

I disable the default `td { background-image: xxx.png }`, and use `td:before { content: 'xx'; position: absolute;}`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayNQKN?editors=1100#0)

Because of static header, DataTables makes the display header one `<table>`, and the scrolling body another `<table>`.  In the latter the `<thead>` is made zero height (it is the default, I did not edit anything).

The above codepen partly copied the styles DataTables uses to made the zero-height `<thead>`.

My `{ content: 'xx'; }` in the zero-height `<thead>` is supposed to be hidden.  It is hidden on Chrome and IE11.

**The problem:** But on Firefox they are shown.  How to hide them in the zero-height `<thead>` on Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this style:

```
td {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Amazing.  I elaborate: with `td { overflow-y: hidden; }`, still showing on Firefox.  With `td { overflow: hidden; }`, ok.